# Write in csv file with dict

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, dictionary

I'm using python 2.7 and need to make a dataset and for this I have a dictionary where I'll put its content in the csv file. This is my current dictionary:

```
dict = {"arthur1.jpg": [0.123,0.456,0.864], "arthur2.jpg": [0.124,0.764,0.965]}
```

in the csv file it would look like this:

```
arthur1.jpg 0.123   0.456   0.864
arthur2.jpg 0.124   0.764   0.965
```

The first column is where the dicts's keys would be, and the next set of columns in the same line are the values of the respective key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn each key-value pair into a row; your values are already a list, just prepend that list with a list literal containing the key:

```
import csv

with open(youcsvfilename, 'rb') as csvf:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvf)    
    for filename, values in dictionary.items():
        csvwriter.writerow([filename] + values)
```

The expression `[filename] + values` produces on new list that serves as your output row. The [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) then takes that list and writes that in the correct format to your CSV file.

Comment: sorry but what I understood is: make two row, one for the key and other for it value, then I didn't understand "prepend", do you mean "append". Could you please be more detailed, if you don't mind? Thanks for the attention

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative:

```
>>> import pyexcel as pe # pip install pyexcel
>>> dict = {"arthur1.jpg": [0.123,0.456,0.864], "arthur2.jpg": [0.124,0.764,0.965]}
>>> sheet = pe.get_sheet(adict=dict)
>>> sheet
Sheet Name: pyexcel_sheet1
+-------------+-------------+
| arthur1.jpg | arthur2.jpg |
+-------------+-------------+
| 0.123       | 0.124       |
+-------------+-------------+
| 0.456       | 0.764       |
+-------------+-------------+
| 0.864       | 0.965       |
+-------------+-------------+
>>> sheet.transpose()
>>> sheet
Sheet Name: pyexcel_sheet1
+-------------+-------+-------+-------+
| arthur1.jpg | 0.123 | 0.456 | 0.864 |
+-------------+-------+-------+-------+
| arthur2.jpg | 0.124 | 0.764 | 0.965 |
+-------------+-------+-------+-------+
>>> sheet.save_as("my.tsv")
>>> with open("my.tsv") as f:
...     print f.read()
... 
arthur1.jpg 0.123   0.456   0.864
arthur2.jpg 0.124   0.764   0.965
```